# rj45 ethernet coupler

Tags: ethernet

I have an outdoor rj45 ethernet coupler where 1 side of it has a flat ethernet cable plugged in. When I test the whole connection with ethernet cable tester the 2nd light is always off where the other 7 blink in unison on the tester. I confirmed the coupler is fine with other non flat cables. I get the same bad result with 2 different flat ethernet cables so I'm guessing it's something in the wiring of the flat cables? Suggestions
Thanks

Comment: Splices, taps, and couplers are not allowed by the _ANSI/TIA 568 Commercial Building Telecommunications Infrastructure Standard_. You are introducing impedance mismatches that can kill the signal.

Answer (score 1):

Flat, round or any other form - all twisted-pair cables intended for Ethernet have the same pinout with pairs 1-2, 3-6, 4-5 and 7-8. Pin 2 is required for all Ethernet variants, even two-pair 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX.

When even a simple cable tester finds a fault then forget about the cable and replace it.

Comment: Agreed, if the cable fails such a simple continuity test, the cable is faulty or the connector is. Replace the cable and/or the coupler.